# Hide a specific div after ajax success data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to hide a specific div content after jquery ajax success.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t922q/

Some of jquery code:

```
  $('.deletethisconent').click(function() {
    // $.ajax({   ....
         success: function(data){
         $(this).closest('.container').hide(); 
         $(".delete_status").html(data);

     });
```

How can I hide one the targeted div after ajax success?
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working) and [jQuery ajax success doesn't work with $(this)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6889855/218196).

Answer (score 4):

`this` refers to the jqXHR object which is the third argument in the success handler.

> **success:**
>
> Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )

You need to store a reference to the outer `this` in a variable if you want to reach it:

```
$('.deletethisconent').click(function() {

     var that = this;

     $.ajax({  
         url: 'echo.php', 
         success: function(data){
             $(that).closest('.container').hide(); 
             $(".delete_status").html(data);
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: `this` refers to the jqXHR object, not the response.

Comment: @FelixKling Right. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to hide the data, so:

```
$('.deletethisconent').click(function() {
    // $.ajax({   ....
    success: function(data){
         $(this).closest('.container').css('display', 'none'); 
         $(".delete_status").html(data);

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to `this` in your click function and then use it:

```
$('.deletethisconent').click(function() {
    var mainElement = this;

    $.ajax({
        success: function(data) {
            $(mainElement).closest('.container').hide(); 
        }
    });
});
```