# JQuery Ajax Type error in success callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I create a button that when clickes do something with Ajax in server and when come back from server color of the button and its text will change (something like +1 add friend in facebook) here is my code in `.js`:

```
$(".blue").on("click", function(){
    var firstName = $(this).prev().prev().text();
    var lastName = $(this).prev().text();
    $(this).text("Add Friend...");
    var data={
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/friendRequest',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(){
            alert(123);
            $(this).removeClass("glass blue");
            $(this).addClass("greenStatic");
            $(this).text("Request sent");
        }
    });
});
```

every thing is OK and request will successfully change the database but when it comeback to the success callback I only see the `alert(123);` on the browser and 3 below lines don't run and my chrome developer tools throw exception of `typeError` I search SO and change `$` sign to `jQuery` but still I have same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your success callback `$(this)` doesn't refer to the button, cache it outside of the success callback, like

```
$(".blue").on("click", function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    ...
    ....
    success:function(){
        ...
        btn.addClass("greenStatic");
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: @mojibuntu yep, `$(this)` refer to jQuery object, use `$(".blue")` again

Comment: Because `$(this)` doesn't refer to the element that triggered the event, I already mentioned in the answer, [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: @vladkras no there might be multiple `.blue` elements. You want to target the one clicked.

Comment: ok, then define `var $this = $(this)` before and use it inside ajax callback

Comment: Yes, that's what I answered.

Comment: @SheikhHeera sorry for that, I was typing and drinking beer while you were answering, so I didn't see you CORRECT answer

Comment: @vladkras, It's ok dear but don't drink bear, it stimulates the brain and also kills cells and creates mental dependency, hope you didn't mind.

Comment: thanks,but I finally don't understand where is the `$(this)` in success refered to ?

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working) and [this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889855/jquery-ajax-success-doesnt-work-with-this).

Answer (score 1):

```
        $(this).removeClass("glass blue");
        $(this).addClass("greenStatic");
        $(this).text("Request sent");
```

Here `this` does not refer to the control, rather it refers to the Ajax request object. So, replace `this` by the control id. It should work.

Something like below...

```
        $("#controlId").removeClass("glass blue");
        $("#controlId").addClass("greenStatic");
        $("#controlId").text("Request sent");
```

Comment: `#controlid` is the id of an element or something else?

Comment: The element on which you want to do the operation addClass and removeClass. Got it?

Comment: Yes that should refer to the button. Please accept the answer, if it helped.

Comment: I have many of these items and don't want to change all of them when one is clicked then I must use `$(this)`

Comment: That's exactly what I've answered, cached it in a variable and used it later.

Comment: @SheikhHeera yes, exactly. I just checked it now.

Comment: Ok. If you want to use it, then just store it in a variable before the Ajax request and use that like... var btn = $(this); Then inside the Ajax block use...  btn.removeClass("glass blue");
            btn.addClass("greenStatic");
            btn.text("Request sent");