# the meaning of 'this' in componentDidMount(), ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Seeking clarification on the meaning of 'this' in this context.  Why do I need to bind 'this' to the callback after the ajax request?  When I check the debugger, it says 'this' is bound to the constructor whether I call bind or not.

```
var BugList = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        bugs: []
    }
},

componentDidMount: function() {

    $.ajax('/api/bugs').done(function(data) {
        this.setState({
            bugs: JSON.parse(data)
        });
    }.bind(this));
},
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889855/jquery-ajax-success-doesnt-work-with-this?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33381852/2733506

Comment: *"When I check the debugger, it says 'this' is bound to the constructor whether I call bind or not.* -- What do you mean by this? There's no constructor in your example. Where do you check the binding of `this`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is because this by default `this` will point to the:

> value of the ThisBinding of the current execution context;

Since your context will change during the time the callback actually runs, `this` will ***not*** refer to your current instance of `BugList`.

The `.bind(this)` essentially declares that no matter the context, set `this` to mean the context of where this function has been created (*ie. `BugList`*)

I'd recommend you look at: [Standard ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), and [Scopes in JS](http://web.archive.org/web/20110725013125/http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/). For a more detailed explanation about this concept!

Comment: Can you please explain the -1?

Comment: *"This answer is not useful (click again to undo)"*